# Is there a blockchain.info for testnet?

Tags: blockchain.info, testnet

I'm trying to test to see if transactions went through or not and blockchain.info is super helpful for this on the real network.

Comment: I’ve collected all of the below answers in the linked Community Wiki.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, blockchain.info has its own testnet service: https://testnet.blockchain.info/

Comment: Awesome. That works really well!

Comment: but https://testnet.blockchain.info/pushtx seems to just redirect to https://www.blockchain.com/btc/pushtx -- which doesn't look like testnet to me

Comment: 2022 update - testnet.blockchain.info does not seem to be working - does anyone have an updated url for this service from blockchain.info or do I have to find another provider?

Answer (score 6):

[www.blocktrail.com/tBTC](https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC) now supports testnet too and has an API for it too (including wallet API)

Comment: It doesn't work anymore at least as of August 2023.

Answer (score 5):

Blockcypher supports [testnet3](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/) and has their own [testnet](https://live.blockcypher.com/bcy/).

Answer (score 4):

[TestNet Bitcoin Block Explorer](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet) appears to be not working too well at the moment. However, [BTCLook](http://testnet.btclook.com/) does appear to be supporting TestNet and looks like a good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Your could also use [Biteasy.com Testnet Block Explorer](https://www.biteasy.com/testnet/blocks) which is pretty fast and also includes a REST API.

Comment: Apparently it's no longer up.

Answer (score 4):

Blockr.io now also supports [Bitcoin TESTNET](http://tbtc.blockr.io/)

[image: Blockr.io Bitcoin TESTNET]

Comment: Dead as of 4 September 2017: https://twitter.com/blockr_io

Answer (score 2):

You can use mine, for now it's on a best effort basis

```
  host: 'rcorbish.ydns.eu',
  port: 18332,
  user: 'bitcoinrpc',
  pass: 'password'
```

Comment: A bitcoin daemon isn't exactly a replacement for blockchain.info. For one, it doesn't have a user interface that a non-technical person can easily use.

Comment: No, was trying to help. If this helps: https://tbtc.blockr.io/

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late to the game here, but blockchain.info do offer testnet resources for SegWit2x. Go to https://testnet5.blockchain.info and you'll see an identical site to the original, but with testnet coins.

Comment: This is actually very helpful to me! Thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: Oh, it's actually bitcoin2x testnet, not bitcoin core testnet. That's very confusing actually. Please note it in the answer

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that! I haven't got around using it yet so I didn't know.

Comment: This not working now.

Comment: the hostname does not resolve.  I tried also just 'testnet' but it just redirects to the mainnet page :(

Answer (score 1):

Coinprism.info has a [testnet blockchain explorer](https://testnet.coinprism.info/). It does colored coins as well.

Note that the SSL certificate is self signed.

Answer (score 1):

Bitpay's [insight](https://insight.is/) project supports and has a [live version of the testnet.](https://test-insight.bitpay.com)

Answer (score 1):

The testnet block explorer and API for blockchain.info doesn't appear to be working at the time of writing (July 2021). It may get fixed but in the meantime or perhaps regardless [blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info/testnet/) can be used instead.

Comment: still works as of this writing.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Blockchain.info has its own testnet service, Check this link https://testnet.blockchain.info/

Comment: dead.
As of this writing, this works:
https://blockstream.info/testnet/