# BlockChain.info testnet wallet and API

Tags: api, blockchain.info, testnet

Does blockchain.info provide wallets and API service for testnet? This information is quite hard to find from their site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a blockchain.info for testnet?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-blockchain-info-for-testnet)

Comment: Not a duplicate: I am not looking for an testnet explorer, but wallet service with API

Comment: @NickODell it's not really a duplicate

Comment: [Testnet ewallet](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/), also [these guys have an API for both mainnet and testnet](https://support.biteasy.com/kb/rest-api/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late, but for others coming to this question, [Blocktrail](https://www.blocktrail.com) have a data and wallet API that supports both Bitcoin mainnet and testnet.

The API provides HD wallets with multi-signature transactions (allowing for full control over your coins should anything ever happen to Blocktrail), and there are currently SDKs for [PHP](https://github.com/blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk-php), [NodeJS](https://github.com/blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk-nodejs) and [Python](https://github.com/blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk-python), with more coming soon.

There are also simple examples included in the SDKs to help you get started, a comprehensive [API documentation](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs), and a couple of working example projects:
 1. [Simple Bitcoin Wallet App](https://github.com/blocktrail/simple-bitcoin-wallet-app)
 2. [Simple Block Explorer](https://github.com/blocktrail/simple-block-explorer)

*Disclaimer*
I am currently one of the core developers for this API

Comment: Blocktrail is pretty much useless. It requires a complex MD5-hash/signature. Thanks but ... no thanks! Did you forget https provides integrity?

Comment: not a big fan of how u need an API key: not needed for calls to the blockchain.info API(which doesn't cover the testnet).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know all steps from create a wallet to broadcast a transaction in test net you can use of my step by step tutorial about this:
[step-by-step-create-and-broadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction-on-testnet](https://medium.com/@athamidn/estep-by-step-create-and-broadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction-on-testnet-588daacc2b7a)

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged on StackExchange sites. Please include the main points of the answer in the answer text as well.